# taking one day before if save data by REST through Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, out-of-the-box

I am saving a date picking from date picker of jqueryUI. While saving I am using REST Services. But the problem is that it taking the date one day before. And timezone is changing (already have chacked my site collection's timezone, It set properly ). And also if I add the record OOTB then it working properly. 
Please suggest what can be the issue.
Thanks

Comment: Could you post your code examples and the output? I'd like to see what you are sending via REST and what is being returned to you after you send the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referring this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342976/changing-timezone-when-conver-to-json/22343251) I have clear the Idea what is actual problem And I got the solution. For taking the date with my current Timezone just few changes required to get correct date, It's:

```
$("#isJson").text(new Date($( "#effectiveDate" ).val()).toDateString());
```

This gives you correct answer

Answer (score 4):

Before I can say for sure, I really need to see your code. But make sure that what you are sending via REST is not the `toString()` output of the date but the `toJSON()` output.

```
myDate.toJSON();
//"2014-03-07T14:48:56.431Z"
```

From your comment I don't think you understand what I am saying. You are sending the ***object*** as a JSON string to the API but you are ***NOT*** sending the date string in the correct JSON format.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RobertKaucher/LfQY7/). Here is the code of the fiddle

```
<div class="container">
    <label>Date:</label>
    <input type="text" value="03/14/2014" id="effectiveDate" />
    <p>
    This is not JSON format:
        <div id="notJson"></div>
    </p>
    <p>
     This is JSON format:
     <div id="isJson"></div>
    </p>
    <p>
     Object in JSON:
        <div id="myObject"></div>
    </p>
</div>


$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $("#notJson").text($( "#effectiveDate" ).val());
    $("#isJson").text(new Date($( "#effectiveDate" ).val()).toJSON());
    var myObject = JSON.stringify({ "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.MYListItem" }, "Title": "DEFAULT", "EffectiveDate": $("#effectiveDate").val() });
    $("#myObject").text(myObject);    
  });
```

Here is what the output looks like. Notice the difference between the JSON format and the non-JSON format of the date?

[image]

Comment: Already I am sending the data by converting in to the JSON format by JSON.stringify(); function of JQuery

Follwing is the code for that


data: JSON.stringify({
"__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.MYListItem" },
"Title": "DEFAULT",
"EffectiveDate": $("#effectiveDate").val()               
})

Comment: What is `$("#effectiveDate").val()` actually outputting?

Comment: I added some more details. Which version of the REST API are you using SP2013 or are you using `ListData.svc`?